# How to append a letter in front of python list element without indicating ''

Tags: python, list, solidity

I stored the string values into the Python list. Then I want to pass this list values to Solidity where the data type needed is byte32[]. So the question is how to declare a char 'b' without indicating '' and append it in front of every element?

The python variable

`name = ['Ken','Rose']`

The name variable that need to be format as below

`sol_par = [b'Ken',b'Rose']`

Comment: Do you just want to encode them as bytes? Like `list(map(str.encode, name))`?

Comment: You can't just go and paste a letter in front of a string! Instead, that `b` is only **printed** to indicate these are [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) objects.

Comment: I only realised that i can just add `bytes` in front of it to indicate it as bytes. Previously I just typed it and it worked as bytes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
sol_par = []
for word in name:
    sol_par.append(bytes(x, 'utf8'))
```

(Edited for correct `bytes` syntax)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just edit it like `sol_par.append(bytes(word, 'utf8'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function with `str.encode`:

```
name = ['Ken','Rose']
sol_par = list(map(str.encode, name))
```

Comment: Note: This assumes UTF-8 is the desired encoding on Python 3 (on Python 2, it's worse, as it simply assumes you want the locale-specific encoding, which makes the result non-portable to systems with other locales). `operator.methodcaller('encode', 'name of encoding goes here')` can replace `str.encode` if you need to specify.